# Assign raw sound file to position android

Tags: android, file, position, int, assign

I am working on sound app that will have around 20 sounds. I have a listView with `onItemClickListener` and I want to have something like this:
If user clicks on position 0, get file that is assigned to position0 and play it, etc etc.
I want to assign file to a position, and then use it to play with MP.
How can I do that? How to assign file to a position

Answer (score 0):

When you work with a listview you have the position number use that.
So:

```
if(position==0){
```

playSound
}